# Java Stream get some values from the Entity containing more than one collection

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

I have a problem about getting some values from more than one list in entity.

Here is the **Person** entity shown below.

Person

....

```
Set<Experience> experinences = new HashSet<Experience>()
Set<Education> educations = new HashSet<Education>()
```

....

Here is the **Experience** entity shown below.

Experience

```
....
name
description
```

Here is the **Education** entity shown below.

Education

```
.....
name
description
```

Here is the **Dto** shown below.

**Dto**

```
String experienceName;
String educationName;
```

What I want to do it to get only name of both experience and education from the entity through Java Stream. I knew **flatmap** is used for that but I have no idea how to do that in more than one collection.

How can I do that?

Comment: How `Experience` and `Education` look like, can you elaborate more please, your question is not clear, maybe with an input/output example.

Comment: @YCF_L I gave some information about it.

Comment: @YCF_L I still wait for your feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to get a list of DTOs per `Person` instance where each education is paired with each experience like this:

```
expOne    edu1
expOne    edu2
expOne    edu3
expTwo    edu1
expTwo    edu2
expTwo    edu3
```

It may be implemented as follows using `flatMap`:

```java
List<Dto> dtos = person.getExperiences()
    .stream()                 // Stream<Experience>
    .map(Experience::getName) // Stream<String> exp names
    .flatMap(expName -> person.getEducations()
            .stream()                // inner Stream<Education>
            .map(Education::getName) // Stream<String> edu names
            .map(eduName -> new Dto(expName, eduName)) // Stream<Dto>
    ) // Stream<Dto>
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I'll try it as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
Set<String> eduExp = Stream.of(
    person.getEducations().stream().map(Education::getName),
    person.getExperiences().stream().map(Experience::getName)
).flatMap(o -> o).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

You can also use Stream.concat

Comment: I shared a DTO to get only name of both Education and Experience. I think it can be wrong.

Comment: Ok. I can help you to do this also with DTO. But I can't imagine how one experience name is connected with one education name. In DTO we have only two String fields. I can allow that DTO should contain Set of education names and Set of experience names. Am I correct?

Comment: How can I do that?